# Use of "exist" in "Can there exist an uncountable planar graph?"

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, verbs, word-usage

> Can there exist an uncountable planar graph?

This usage of *exist* bothers me. In this context, my understanding is that it is used as a replacement for *be*. That looks very strange to me. However, I found it in the writing of a person who is very good at teaching and explaining, and I guess it might be actually correct. Is it?

EDIT: This is actually a title of [a Mathematics Stack Exchange question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/712013/can-there-exist-an-uncountable-planar-graph).

Comment: Yes. It's perfectly grammatical. But if you ever heard the expression 'Can there exist ...' outside a university symposium (or EL website), I would be extremely surprised. It is probably better than the far more normal ordering 'Can a 7 foot spider exist?' (which would probably have an 'actually' inserted) here as it focuses emphasis in a better way.

Comment: @VividD Where does the question come from? It looks like mathematical jargon to me. It may be an odd way of speaking in general conversation, but to a mathematician it's a very normal way of asking the question.

Comment: What bothers you about it?

Comment: @Matt, why is 'to exist' so special verb? I can't imagine any other verb in similar construction (other than 'to be').

Comment: So your questions seem to be "Are there any other verbs besides _be_ which can substitute in the construction _Can there [VERB] [SUBJECT]_ '?

Comment: @Matt This would be a logical 'follow-up' question, I guess...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This use of *exist* instead of *be* is common, not only in mathematics, but also in philosophy. Although in everyday life, we make little distinction, if any, between the two, in general, the verb *be* when used independently, seems to carry with it a sense of sentient existence, whereas *exist* lacks that connotation, and is therefore more "neutral".

Now, for the word order in the sentence. As Edwin Ashworth mentioned in his comment, in everyday language we would probably find a sentence like:

> Can a 7 foot spider exist?

rather than

> Can there exist a 7 foot spider?

However, in the fields of philosophy and mathematics, one usually is not interested in teh existence of such mundane phenomena which can so concisely be described.

You *could* phrase your sentence as:

> Can an uncountable planar graph exist?

However, it is not unlikely that in a similar context I am not wondering about a mere uncountable planar graph, but one that has many more properties. I might wonder a about an uncountable, limited dimensional, planar graph that is not identical to an earlier-described construct.

Now, if I ask:

> Can an uncountable, limited dimensional, planar graph that is not identical to an earlier-described construct exist?

The sentence becomes a lot less clear: halfway the sentence I start wondering *what that thing you are describing is supposed to be able to do*!

Therefore the main verb, *exist* is moved to the front of the sentence, so it is clear from the start that I want to know something about the possible existence of what I am about to describe:

> Can there exist an uncountable, limited dimensional, planar graph that is not identical to an earlier-described construct?

Comment: Interestingly, the naturalness and neutralness of the _there_-based constructions is much higher if the verb is _be_, rather than _exist_: “Can there be a seven-foot spider?” is fine, whereas “Can a seven-foot spider be?” is archaic or awkward at best.

Comment: True, "can a spider be?" is something I would expect in a theological treatise on the existence of souls in non-human animals...